# Dropdown menu in safari not showing dropdown-items

Tags: python, css, django

My dropdown menu works on Chrome(Desktop & Mobile) and Firefox(Desktop & Mobile) but seems to not work on Safari (Desktop) as well as Chrome (Tablet).

Here's what it looks like working on Chrome
[image]

And here's how it looks on Safari
[image]

HTML:

```
<button type="button" id="platform" class="btn btn-orange dropdown-toggle mr-2" data-toggle="dropdown"
                        aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Select Platform
                </button>

<div class="dropdown-menu" id="plat-form-options">
                    {% for platform in game.platform.all %}
                        <option class="dropdown-item" value="{{ platform.id }}"
                                onclick="platFormSelect('{% url 'title-updates-ajax' slug=game.slug platform_id=platform.id %}', '{{ platform }}')">{{ platform }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
```

Javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            if ($("#plat-form-options option").length > 0) {
                $("#plat-form-options option")[0].click();
            }

        });


        function platFormSelect(url, platform) {
            $('#platform').text(platform);


            $.get(url, function (response) {
                        $('#updates_data').html(response);

                    })
                    .done(function () {

                    })
                    .fail(function () {

                    });

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `<option>` tags should be `<a>` tags instead since they are not wrapped within a `<select>`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option

Try this:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" id="plat-form-options">
  {% for platform in game.platform.all %}
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-item" value="{{ platform.id }}"
              onclick="platFormSelect('{% url 'title-updates-ajax' slug=game.slug platform_id=platform.id %}', '{{ platform }}')">{{ platform }}</a>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: You had me looking in the right direction. I had to change option tag to an a tag. If you update your answer I'll mark it as the correct answer. Thank, man.